# FFMPEG API: How to connect to RTSP stream using av_open_input_file?

Tags: ffmpeg, rtsp-client

I'm trying to connect to some RTSP stream using av_open_input_file() like this:

`AVFormatContext* ic;
avcodec_register_all();
av_register_all();
av_open_input_file(&ic, "rtsp://login:password@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/videoinput_1/mjpeg/media.stm", NULL, 4096, NULL);`

It always returns 'file not found'. The same url, though, I can see in, say, VLC player. Do I do something wrong in my code?

I'm using FFMPEG 0.6, shall I use the latest instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turned out I did not enable network support when building FFMPEG.

The following options worked for me:

--enable-network --enable-protocol=tcp --enable-demuxer=rtsp --enable-decoder=h264

Comment: I didn't find --enable-protocol=rtsp. How did you fix that?

Comment: I used --enable-network --enable-protocol=tcp --enable-demuxer=rtsp --enable-decoder=h264 in the configure file, that did let me enable rtsp

Comment: -enable-demuxer=rtsp solved my problem as well. I didn't need h264 as my app works only with audio streaming.

Comment: @AlexanderKulyakhtin parameters are exactly what I did need to have RTSP streaming work. I know thanks comments need to be avoided, but this answer can be really useful to other users too, so be reassured this is the real deal!

Comment: Nowadays adding `--enable-demuxer=rtsp` already adds the necessary protocols (rtp udp http tcp). I believe `--enable-network` doesn't exist anymore...?