# ffmpeg rtmp streaming issue

Tags: ffmpeg, rtmp, wowza

I am trying to stream my webcam video using the ffmpeg to wowza media server on linux..

```
ffmpeg -re -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 -acodec libfacc -vcodec libx264 -f h264 rtmp://localhost:1935/live/test
```

This is the command I used for some reason it doesn't seem to work as I am not able to run the example that came with wowza. I tried using flash media live encoder to send a rtmp to my wowza server and it works.

Any pointers on how to solve this problem.

I build ffmpeg from their git repo with the following config

```
--enable-gpl --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-version3 --enable-x11grab
```

ffmpeg -protocols says it has rtmp input/output support

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With these build options my FFMPEG build does receive and decode rtsp streams

--enable-network --enable-protocol=tcp --enable-demuxer=rtsp --enable-decoder=h264

I have answered  a similar question here [FFMPEG API: How to connect to RTSP stream using av_open_input_file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7906944/ffmpeg-api-how-to-connect-to-rtsp-stream-using-av-open-input-file)

Comment: Why not to take a ready FFMPEG build instead of building yourself?  There's a site with ready FFMPEG builds, don't remember URL though.
Worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Your second -f switch, for the container format, should be mp4 not h264. H264 is a codec not a container format

Answer (score 0):

In order to stream to rtmp, one should select '**flv**' output format like this:

> ffmpeg -re -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 -acodec libfacc -vcodec
>   libx264 -f flv rtmp://localhost:1935/live/test