# Has anyone gotten a windows build of FFMPEG to publish to Akamai's CDN via RTMP?

Tags: ffmpeg, akamai

I am trying to live stream a file to Akamai's servers via RTMP from flash and I cannot get past the authentication step even though I know I am using the right username and password (the credentials work in FMLE).  I Have found some posts online but they are older and its difficult because no one ever reports what build of FFMPEG they are using.

Has anyone gotten this to work with Windows binaries?

Comment: Did you try this? http://stackoverflow.com/q/8270042

Comment: Well yes and know. I can get it to stream through FFMPEG as long as there is no authentication on the server.  Specifically trying to stream to Akamai.

Comment: The command I am using is ffmpeg -re -i "c:\ffmpg\47505_21.mp4" -c:v libx264 -b:v 500k -an -x264opts keyint=50 -g 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p -f flv -loglevel debug "rtmp://p.epXXXXX.i.akamaientrypoint.net/EntryPoint/40_1_1@XXXXXX flashver=FMLE/3.0\20(compatible;\20FMSc/1.0) live=true pubUser=XXXXX pubPasswd=XXXXX"  Which fails with bad password, but I know it is the correct username and password (they work in FMLE)

Comment: Hi! I'm currently struggling with the same issue... If you ever got it working, would you be kind enough to post your workaround! :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use a build of ffmpeg with akamai auth support  http://sinclairmediatech.com/building-ffmpeg-for-adobe-media-server-akamai-auth/

Comment: You should consider taking the important parts from the link into your answer so that if the link goes dead in the future your answer is still useful.